# Refactoring PostgreSQL WITH query with many update statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string of SQL queries that need to be executed in order, and each require a `WITH` query. Something like this:

```
WITH diff AS (
  SELECT NOW() - created_at as time_diff FROM table_a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE table_x SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff);

WITH diff AS (
  SELECT NOW() - created_at as time_diff FROM table_a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE table_y SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff);

WITH diff AS (
  SELECT NOW() - created_at as time_diff FROM table_a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE table_a SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff);
```

This is a slightly contrived example, but the intention is to "shift" the created_at timestamp of all records of a certain number of tables. Because `table_a` is included in all the `WITH` queries, it needs to be the last table to be updated or everything else would be wrong.

Ideally I'd just want to do something like this:

```
WITH diff AS (
  SELECT NOW() - created_at as time_diff FROM table_a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE table_x SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff)
UPDATE table_y SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff)
UPDATE table_a SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff);
```

Both because it's more concise and because then the order wouldn't really matter. But this is obviously not legal syntax.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put each update (except the last one) in a CTE:

```
WITH diff AS (
  SELECT NOW() - created_at as time_diff FROM table_a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
), upd_x as (
  UPDATE table_x SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff)
), upd_y as (
  UPDATE table_y SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff)
)
UPDATE table_a SET created_at = created_at + (SELECT time_diff FROM diff);
```